# How to use GITHUB code in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

i need to create a mega-menu from a list in SharePoint online. as similar to the once below to my SharePoint. I have never used or tried to add GITHUB code sample to my SharePoint.
Please let me know how to use the code samples from GITHUB like the one below.
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-mega-menu

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the sample you are pointing to is using the SharePoint Term Store. And not a list as source.

You also need to use SPFx dev tools to complete that sample. Please have a look at this page for more information regarding SPFx development. [https://docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)

You can download the repository as a zip using the method described in the image below:

[image]

One other way is to use GIT which is a way of version control your code. I like to use the SourceTree application for easy management of git repositories. [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In the [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions) you provide, it tells how to use the examples.

You need to download files via clicking "Clone or Download" button. Then open CMD to navigate to the cloned repository folder, follow the [steps](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions#using-the-samples).

Comment: CMD ? . Sounds really complicated.  I thought its a simple matter of downloading the code and editing it Visual studio to make it work. But it seems not the case. is there any step by step guide to use it.